# Display map from Geoserver using OpenLayers 6

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-6

I tried to use TileWMS and ImageWMS, but unable to display the map that I have configured in the geoserver.I am not sure if my code is correct.

```js
var map = new ol.Map({
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLotLat([103.851959, 1.290270]),
        zoom: 5
    }),
    layers: [],
    target: "map"
});

var layer = new ol.layer.Image({
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
        params:{
            "LAYERS": "space:space"
        },
        serverType: "geoserver"
    });

map.addLayer(layer);
```

Comment: what happens? do you see a map?

Comment: No. I didnt see the map

Comment: what is returned? is it an error or an empty image? what does the GeoServer log file say happened?

Comment: Hi Ian, I went to the Geoserver log file and saw the error message, it is due to the rendering memory.  I have increased the WMS rendering memory and it is working now, I am able to display the map now

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, it should be `ol.proj.fromLonLat` (and not `ol.proj.fromLotLat`)